# crear un plugin que incluya codigo php

Tags: php, wordpress-plugin

hola estoy desarrollando mi primer plugin y me encuentro con el siguiente problema. Es un plugin que crea un shortcode que al insertarlo en una pagina me muestra un hola mundo. Este es el codigo del plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Hola Mundo
 * Plugin URI: https://pablomonteserin.com
 * Description: Inserta un hola mundo
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Luilli
 * Author URI: https://pablomonteserin.com
 * License: GPL2
 */

$etiqueta="hola mundo";
add_shortcode( "holamundo", function($atts, $content){
$output = 
'<html>
<body>
<?php echo $etiqueta;?>
</body>
</html>';
return $output;
});
?>
```

y no me muestra el «hola mundo». ¿como hago para insertar la variable php ($etiqueta) en la salida ($output) del shortcode?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Lo que está en el contexto de `add_shortcode` es la variable `$content` y si quieres pasar información en la llamada del shortcode debes usar `$atts`. [Revisa los ejemplos de la documentación](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/#user-contributed-notes) y dinos qué no entiendes en ellos. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente (cómo piensas llamar al shortcode y qué quieres que ocurra)? Pon un ejemplo de caso de uso concreto.

Comment: lo que quiero es que en la pagina que uso el shortcode "holamundo", me aparezca en pantalla "hola mundo". Pero quiero hacerlo con la variable "$etiqueta" utilizando php. Con html solo ya lo hice y funciona bien, pero quiero añadirle codigo php. Por ejemplo, en una pagina en blanco añado el shortcode [holamundo] y en la pagina tiene que mostrarse el mensaje "hola mundo". Un saludo.

Comment: [Revisa la documentación de la API shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Si tú quieres mandar datos desde el shortcode la función sería más o menos así: `function holamundo_func( $atts ) { return $atts['msg'] ; }` Para registrar el shortcode: `add_shortcode( 'shortcode_holamundo', 'holamundo_func' );` Y para pasar los datos que quieres mostrar desde el shortcode: `[shortcode_holamundo msg="Hola mundo o lo que sea que quieras enviar"]`